# How to replace value with linebreak and show it in b-modal (with linebreaks)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, line-breaks, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a `string` like following: **Hello / my name / is B0BBY / how / are you ?**

Now I want to show this string in a `<b-modal>` and replace all `/` (Slash) with a linebreak.. I've tried following:

```
var newString = actualString.replaceAll(" / ", "\n")
```

If I `console.log` this `newString` it shows in my console with a linebreak. But if I'm using it in my `b-modal` it shows not with a linebreak, it's all in one line.

I think there is a pretty simple solution for it, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities. If you want to use `\n` in your HTML, you have to set a CSS property `white-space: pre-line;` for the parent element.

Or you can simply replace `\n` with `<br>`.
Both are possible.

`var newString = actualString.replaceAll(" / ", "<br>")`

```js
actualString = "Hello / my name / is B0BBY / how / are you ?";
var newString = actualString.replaceAll(" / ", "\n")
console.log(newString)

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = newString;
```

```html
<div id="out" style="white-space: pre-line; "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines in HTML are supposed to be separated with block elements (`<p>`, etc) or `<br>`. Changing the way multiline text is rendered (as another answer shows) is a hack that is not needed under normal circumstances when HTML layout can be directly affected.

The string can be separated and rendered as an array:

```
<b-modal>
  <p v-for="(line, index) in lines(actualString)" :key="index">{{line}}</p>
```

Where `lines` is a method (can be converted to a filter or a computed):

```
lines: actualString => actualString.replaceAll(" / ", "\n")
```